# If a complex valued function $f$ has a pole, does this mean that the range of $f$ is equal to $\mathbb{C}$?

Tags: complex-analysis

One definition of a complex valued function that has a pole at $a$ is the following;

If $a$ is an isolated singularity of $f$, then $a$ is a pole of $f$ if $\lim_{z\to a}|f(z)| = \infty$.

I don't think it's necessarily true that a function being unbounded would imply that it can take on any value in $\mathbb{C}$; Maybe the range of the function is something like the right half of the plane, or something like that.

More specifically, I'm trying to answer the following question from Conway;

Let $f$ be analytic in $G=\{z:0<|z-a|<r\}$, except that there is a sequence of poles $\{a_n\}$ in $G$ with $a_n \rightarrow a$. Show that for any $\omega \in \mathbb{C}$, there is a sequence $\{z_n\}$ in $G$ with $\lim z_n = a$ and $\omega = \lim f(z_n)$.

But I'm not sure how it could be true that $\omega = \lim f(z_n)$ for *any* $\omega \in \mathbb{C}$ without having the range of $f$ being equal to $\mathbb{C}$.

I'd really appreciate some guidance or thoughts.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

No, $1/z$ is never equal to 0 for example

Comment: Ahh. Right. Good point.

Thanks.

Comment: For Conway's question, $w$ isn't required to be in the range of $f$. It does have to be a _limit point_ of the range of $f$.

Comment: Would it be sufficient to show (is it even true?) that the range of our given $f$ is dense in $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: Unfortunately the required statement is stronger, not only do you need the image of $f$ to be dense in $\mathbb C$, you need the image of $f$ on every neighbourhood of $a$ to be dense in $\mathbb C$. I don't know the solution here, but this question reminds of the Casorati-Weierstrass theorem

Answer (score 3):

The range of $1/z$ doesn't include $0$.

Answer (score 2):

I think the statement is $f\colon D \backslash \{z_0\}$, with $z_0$ an essential singularity ( that is, the [Laurent series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurent_series) at $z_0$ has infinitely many terms with negative exponent. Then the image of $f$ is dense in $\mathbb{C}$. See [Casorati-Weierstrass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casorati%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem) theorem.

Comment: I think it is also worth mentioning Picard theorem

Comment: So in this case would I want to show that $a$ is the essential singularity?

If so, is that even true? An essential singularity has to be an isolated singularity, but the sequence $a_n \rightarrow a$, so there's no neighborhood around $a$ on which $f$ is analytic.

Comment: Actually after examining the proof of Casorati-Weierstrass, the same proof should work for your problem

Comment: I'm still a little confused.

If $a$ is to be an essential singularity, don't we first require it to be an isolated singularity?
But if that's the case, then the fact that $\{a_n\}$ is a sequence of poles converging to $a$ would prevent $a$ from meeting the "isolated" criteria.

Comment: @Bears: Ignore the definitions and just do the trick : $\frac{1}{f(z)-\omega}$.  If this function were bounded, it would not have any singular points.  What can you conclude now about $f$?

Comment: Well that would mean there's no $z$ such that $f(z) = a$.

But I'm not seeing how that moves the problem along. Maybe I'm being a little dense (pun partially intended).

Comment: Oh wait. Whoops. I just noticed you had an $\omega$ in your denominator. Not $a$

Okay. Now I think I see where you're going. 
I need to push some more stuff around, but I think I'm getting a better idea of how to solve this problem.

Thanks a bunch for your help